# Linking a DE to all contact records within an attribute group

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, contactbuilder, attribute-group

We would like to link a DE in data designer to all contact records present in our MC BU. The DE contains data regarding what day is today and today's weather.

```
DE fields:
Day (number) 
WeatherDescription (text)
```

This DE can contain only 1 record at a given moment which is overwritten everyday by an automation. This record is relevent to all contacts in the system and we would like to access it in all journeys in journey builder as a contact data.

Any advice how to achieve that?
Thanks,
Barak

Comment: You cannot do that because it is not in any way related to the Contact data

Comment: Thanks zuzannamj. Any alternative idea how to access this data from journey bulilder?

Comment: This seems like an XY (https://xyproblem.info/) problem - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: We are trying to do descion splits in jounrey builder that their logic is based on whatever weather description (rainy, sunny etc...) suits for today. Those descion splits should be implemented on many journeys we have (that's why we thought to link this data directly to the contact model). Thanks

Comment: Is weather specific to each contact (e.g. lookup based on postcode)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be a very elegant solution, but what you COULD do, is either create a *WeatherDescription* field on your main contact data extension, or a replica of it, with only the *ContactKey* and *WeatherDescription* fields.

In both cases, you will be able to map these DEs to your contact model in Data Designer. In your first case, you will need a query which joins the weather DE on your main contact data extension, and in the second case, a query which replicates all your contact keys, and joins the weather DE, writing this result into the aforementioned contact replica DE.

This will, AFAIK, be the only way of providing access to weather data in your decision splits.